# How can i read all the Attributes mentioned in the xml in one go using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to read all the attributes value specified in the xml.Please find below the sample xml as follows:

```
<DrWatson>
  <Bugs Name="STATE" TestCondition="STATE">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  <Bugs Name="STATUS" TestCondition="STATUS">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>    
</DrWatson>
```

I would like to read all the attributes mention under `Test Condition` in one go.
Currently i am trying to perform this operation using the following code:

```
XmlDocument XDoc = new DrWatsonCore().LoadXMLFromFile(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile);
                XmlNodeList Update_Bugs = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Bugs");
                string attrVal_New = "";
                int m = 0;
                attrVal_New = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;
```

After using this code i am only able to read only one attribute as "STATE" whereas there is another attribute as "STATUS" is not getting read.
Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15970511/293712

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ to XML you can select all distinct test condition values:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var testConditions = xdoc.Root.Elements("Bugs")
                         .Select(b => (string)b.Attribute("TestCondition"))
                         .Distinct();
```

Output:

```
STATE
STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Output from code below:

```
Name:STATE
TestCondition:STATE
Name:STATUS
TestCondition:STATUS
```

---

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(@"
<DrWatson>
  <Bugs Name=""STATE"" TestCondition=""STATE"">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  <Bugs Name=""STATUS"" TestCondition=""STATUS"">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>    
</DrWatson>");


foreach( XmlNode a in xdoc.SelectNodes( "//*/@*")){
    Console.Out.WriteLine( a.Name + ":" + a.Value );
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to use the attribute values as string further in my code.How can i use it as string.