# XML to Linq C#, no results

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to grab the Filename from the below XML code where the partNum passed in by the end user matches the partNum of a JES.
My current code yields 0 results.

I will also be trying to grab the disrete attribute as well.

```
<JESs>
    <JES partNum="116102440002" discrete="true">
       <Filename>116-10244-0002_ILLK Collimator Cover Assy_Rev 3.docx</Filename>
    </JES>
    <JES partNum="116102440003" discrete="false">
        <Filename>ILLK Collimator in Gimbal_Rev 4.docx</Filename>
    </JES>
    <JES partNum="116102440004" discrete="true">
        <Filename>116-10244-0004_Collimator Cover Installation_Rev 1.docx</Filename>
     </JES>
     <JES partNum="116102440005" discrete="true">
        <Filename>116-10244-0005_Collimator Lens Assembly_Rev 2.docx</Filename>
     </JES>
 </JESs>
```

C# Code

```
var FileName = (from n in xml.Descendants("JESs") where n.Element("JES").Attribute("partNum").Value == Convert.ToString(partNum) select n.Elements().Descendants().Elements()).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry but what were you thinking when you write this `n.Elements().Descendants().Elements()` ?

Comment: Elements() is JES, the Descendents of JES is Filename, grab all Filenames.

Comment: @Spitfire19 But you can't call `.Descendants` on a list of Elements, or `.Elements` on a list of Descendants.

Comment: Yeah, got confused when looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970161/reading-multiple-child-nodes-of-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify (and fix) your query like this:

```
var partNumber = Convert.ToString(partNum);
var result = xml.Descendants("JES")
             .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("partNum") == partNumber);

if(result != null)
{
    var fileName = (string)result.Element("Filename");
}
```

Comment: What was this style of coding called again where you use FirstOrDefault() and Where() instead of SQL-like statements? I've used it in Linq to SQL projects before.

Comment: it is extension method syntax. all of your queries in sql-like syntax are translated into this.

Comment: Ended going up with a variation of this one, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
var FileNames = (from n in xml.Descendants("JESs")
                 where n.Element("JES").Attribute("partNum").Value == Convert.ToString(partNum)
                 select n.Element("JES").Element("Filename")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I will also look at Selman22's because I like using that style once I get familiarized with how to access the data Sql-style.

Comment: There is a problem with this one, it only successfully grabs the filename from the first JES.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
    var fileName = (from x in xml.Elements()
                      where x.Attribute("partNum").Value == "xxxx"

                      select x.Element("Filename").Value).FirstOrDefault();

//replace xxxx with actual value
```

If no elements found for given partNum, fileName will be `null`

Comment: try this to get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Selman22: Updated answer. We need to check for null for fileName

Comment: no it will throw exception because you are iterating over all the elements and all elements don't have partNum attribute

Comment: @Selman22 : As per xml format specified in question by OP has partNum in all elements.