# Reading certain nodes from elements one at a time of xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm trying to read through .xml -file and get information out of there. Here is a sample of the .xml -file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XmlFile>
  <xmlsource>
    <Name>TestXml</Name>
    <filename>MyXmlFile.xml</filename>
    <Information Key="GeneralInfo"/>
    <Products>
        <Product>
            <ProductName>Product1</ProductName>
            <Name Key="SomeName"/>
            <Usages>
                <Usage>
                    <Specs>
                        <Spec1 Key="Moving"/>
                        <Spec2 Key="Lifting"/>
                    </Specs>
                    <Info1>
                        <MovingInfo1>yes</MovingInfo1>
                    </Info1>
                    <Info2>Noup</Info2>
                    <MoreSpecs>
                        <ProductModel1>
                            <DetInfo1>DetInfo1</DetInfo1>
                            <DetInfo2>DetInfo2</DetInfo2>
                        </ProductModel11>
                    </MoreSpecs>
                </Usage>
            </Usages>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProductName>Product2</ProductName>
            <Name Key="SomeName2"/>
            <Usages>
                <Usage>
                    <Specs>
                        <Spec1 Key="Moving"/>
                        <Spec2 Key="Lifting"/>
                    </Specs>
                    <Info1>
                        <MovingInfo1>not</MovingInfo1>
                    </Info1>
                    <Info2>Yes</Info2>
                    <MoreSpecs>
                        <ProductModel1>
                            <DetInfo1>DetInfo1</DetInfo1>
                        </ProductModel1>
                    </MoreSpecs>
                </Usage>
                <Usage>
                    <Specs>
                        <Spec1 Key="Turning"/>
                    </Specs>
                    <Info1>
                        <TurningInfo1>Infoooo</TurningInfo1>
                    </Info1>
                    <Info2>No</Info2>
                    <MoreSpecs>
                        <ProductType1>
                            <DetInfo1>DetInfo1</DetInfo1>
                        </ProductType1>
                    </MoreSpecs>
                </Usage>
            </Usages>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</xmlsource>
```

(This is just a sample, original file has a lot more data in it.)

I want to know only the values of `ProductName` and `Spec1`. As you can see from the sample, 'Product2' has two different values of `Spec1`: 'Moving' and 'Turning'.

**What I'm trying to achieve**:

Read `ProductName` ("Product1") from the first `<Product>` and then the `Spec1` ("Moving"), then do something with the information. After that, move to next `<Product>`, read `ProductName` ("Product2"), `Spec1` ("Moving") and the other `Spec1` ("Turning"), and skipping all the other possible `Spec` values - meaning, that I want only `Spec1` value. And so on go through the hole file.

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
public void getNodes(string filepath)
    {
        xmlFilePath = filepath;
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
        XmlNodeList products = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Product");
        XmlNodeList productnames = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Product/ProductName");
        XmlNodeList specs = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Product//Spec1");

        AllocConsole();

        Console.WriteLine(products.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(specs.Count);

        foreach (XmlNode xn in specs)
        {
            XmlAttributeCollection spec1Atts = xn.Attributes;
            Console.WriteLine(spec1Atts["Key"].Value.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(products.Item(i).InnerText);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

This is the closest I have got (closest to what I'm trying to do).

There, first I have load the .xml -file.

Then, in lines containing `XmlNodeList` etc. I'm filtering with those requirements.

Here (below), is being checked the amount of products specs:

```
Console.WriteLine(products.Count);
Console.WriteLine(specs.Count);
```

Finally I'm printing out the values which has been read. With this, the print-out is obviously:

- First comes out the amounts
- Second comes the specs
- And finally the productnames

As said above, I want `ProductNames` and `Spec1's` to be "linked" together.

I tried many methods e.g. shown in here: [Reading multiple child nodes of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970161/reading-multiple-child-nodes-of-xml-file)

Somehow I couldn't make any example work in my situation. Maybe it's because in my case, there is so deep parent-child pairs?

I can't change the structure of the .xml -file. If I could, I would have changed it already...

So, my question is: Could someone show me a hint/way how to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is traverse the hierarchy.  In the revised code below, I find the ProductName, then ***within*** that, I look for the next node and so on until I find the Specs that correspond to that product.

```
    private static void getNodes(string filePath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
        var productNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Product");
        if (productNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode product in productNodes)
            {
                var childNodes = product.ChildNodes;
                foreach (XmlNode child in childNodes)
                {
                    if (child.Name == "ProductName")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(child.InnerText);
                    }
                    else if (child.Name == "Usages")
                    {
                        var childNodes2 = child.ChildNodes;
                        foreach (XmlNode child2 in childNodes2)
                        {
                            if (child2.Name == "Usage")
                            {
                                var childNodes3 = child2.ChildNodes;
                                foreach (XmlNode child3 in childNodes3)
                                {
                                    if (child3.Name == "Specs")
                                    {
                                        var childNodes4 = child3.ChildNodes;
                                        foreach (XmlNode child4 in childNodes4)
                                        {
                                            foreach (XmlNode a in child4.Attributes)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine($"  {a.InnerText}");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope that helps.  If so, please vote for my answer because I need the reputation.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This basically works, and now I get the logic, but as I mentioned above (unclearly though, I will edit it, so it is clearer), I need only the `Spec1` value. I want to skip all the other 'Specs'... Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Answering to my own question, which was "childish"... : Just add one more if-statement: `if (child4.Name.Contains("1")){}`. Thanks for the help! +1:ed :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to retrieve the specs for each product and you want to use them together. (Apologies if I don't fully get it). if that is the case you can try probing the product element directly in your example loop. like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++) {
   var specs = products[i].SelectNodes("Usages/Usage/Specs")[0].ChildNodes;
     for (int j = 0; j < specs.Count; j++)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}->{1}", products[i].FirstChild.InnerText, specs[j].Attributes["Key"].Value);
 }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Very efficient, but user2263986 shows step by step for a programmer just beginning with XML.  Gave you both +1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This basically works, but as I mentioned above (unclearly though, I will edit it, so it is clearer), I need only the `Spec1` value. I want to skip all the other 'Specs'... Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Answering to my own question, which was "childish"... : Just add one if-statement: if (specs[j].Name.Contains("1")){}. Thanks for the help! +1:ed :)